# When does a null integral implies that a form is exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, differential-forms

It is trivial to prove that the integration of a $(n-1)$ exact form on the boundary of a $n$-manifold is 0. What about the contraposative ? If the integration of a $(n-1)$-form on the boundary of a $n$-manifold is 0, is this form exact ? If not, are there particular conditions to satisfy for this to be the case ?

For example, in the case of $S^1$, any $1$-form can be written as $f(\theta)d\theta=c d\theta+dg(\theta)$, $c$ being the integral around $S^1$, and $g$ a differentiable function on $S^1$. Now in this case if the integral is 0, it implies that the form is exact. I wondered in the general case if such decomposition is always possible, because if so, it can be proven that the integral being 0 implies that the form is exact. Is this correct ?

Comment: Won't any closed $(n-1)$-form on an $n$-manifold integrate to 0 on the boundary of that manifold?

Comment: The question did not hypothesize it being closed, I think.

Comment: Since beign closed is a necessary condition to be exact in any case, maybe I could rephrase my question as "If the integration of a (n−1)-form closed form on the boundary of a n-manifold is 0, is this form exact ?"

Comment: If the form is closed and the domain is contractible, that implies that the integral is 0 (by the Poincarré lemma), but I think I am looking at the implication in the other direction, from the value of the integral to the characterization of the form.

Comment: because it 'implies' the integral is path independent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the result you are looking for is this: [Top deRham cohomology group of a compact orientable manifold is 1-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228502/), with the isomorphism $H^n_{dR}(M^n)\to \mathbb R$ given by $\omega\mapsto \int_M \omega$. (One should add "connected" to the assumptions.) In your question, $n$ is actually $n-1$.

The proof of $H^n_{dR}(M^n)\approx \mathbb R$  is not hard but lengthy: see section 8.1, titled *de Rham cohomology in the top dimension*, of [Nigel Hitchin's notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/Differentiable_manifolds/Chapter_3.pdf).

See also [Poincaré Duality with de Rham Cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81844/). And for the non-compact case, [De Rham cohomology for non-compact manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93426/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask a complementary question ? In the case of a non-top cohomology group, say for the torus as in http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Torus , is it possible to link the rank $\binom {n} {k}$ to the values of various integrals on the domain ?

Comment: @vkubicki Interesting, but a new question should be posted as  separate question, not as a comment..

Comment: You are right, the scope is a bit larger than a comment. So there it is, waiting at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453644/relation-between-de-rham-cohomology-and-integration .

Answer (score 6):

Stokes' theorem works both ways, but you have to be careful. In particular, a $n$-form $\omega$ is *closed* if and only if its integral over *every* $n$-boundaries is zero, not just one particular!

For every $(n+1)$-dimensional region $\Omega$ we have:
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}\omega=\int_\Omega d\omega.
$$

If the expression on the left is zero for *every* $\Omega$, so is the one on the right, and it means that $d\omega=0$.

If we want $\omega$ to be *exact*, then we don't have to limit ourselves to $n$-boundaries, but we want its integral to be zero *on every closed region*!
That is, any region $A$ with $\partial A=0$.

This because what cause a closed form not to be exact are the very "holes".

I don't know if from this requirement you can explicitly find that $\omega=d\eta$ for some $\eta$ (that is, I don't know if this reasoning provides you such an $\eta$).

What is immediate to check (just use Stokes), though, is that exact forms yield a zero integral over general closed regions, not just boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

No, and my limited knowledge of the topic is that it depends heavily on the topology of a space. For instance, in a multiply connected 2-manifold, there are closed forms which are not exact (they are not the boundary of any submanifold, since they "go around they hole").

Comment: OK. I edited my question regarding the impact of the holes in a manifold.